# Print statement didn't worked when typed print "coding is coding"

Tags: python

```
print "coding is coding"
```

I am using python 3.8.0

Comment: `print` is not a statement any more but a function so you need brackets.

Comment: There is no print statement in Python 3, `print` is a function. You must be learning Python 2, but you really should learn Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since python 2:

```
print("coding is coding")
```